# Re-size all images in a folder to 90% of original height and width (windows)

Tags: windows, image, batch-file, command-line, image-resizing

I have a situation where I need to re-size a lot of images in a folder by a certain %. All the images are different heights and widths so I cannot just say 400 x 300 reduced by 10% is now "X by Y". It's also very inefficient to go through each one and do the math of reducing each one by 10%.

Is there a way to do this from the command line in Windows?

**A one liner would be my ideal solution**, but if that's not possible maybe a batch file?

If that's still not possible I will take recommendations for **free** software but it must be able to reduce image height and width by a percentage. As stated before the images are all different sizes so I do not know the exact dimensions I'm re-sizing them to. I just need them about 10% - 20% smaller. So a tool that will mass re-size to say "200 x 400" will not help me.

All of my research so far has turned up nothing.

Comment: Photoshop has a batching process to apply actions to everything in a folder.  File > Automate > Batch.    So uh... are you removing watermarks?

Comment: No, no watermarks, i dont have access to photoshop though. I guess i could do the trial just for this process if it would help.

Comment: it is even possible with the windows [built-in tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630819(v=vs.85).aspx) though at the moment I have no ready to use script.

Comment: I don't understand the down vote for this question. It was well written and it provides value to the community. I also have not seen any duplicates. Haters gonna hate

Comment: Downvotes are because you show no attempt to resolve the problem yourself.

Comment: @SomethingDark fair enough, thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify

```
mogrify -resize 90x90% *.* -path c:\resizedimages
```

Assuming you run the command from the folder containing the images and the images are the only thing in the folder.

Answer (score 2):

I use this software for simple resizes:  http://www.multipleimageresizer.net/

We also write PHP scripts to do this work ... would you want to see those?

Comment: no thank you to the php, but thank you for the helpful link. +1